# Ruby on Rails: LoadError: No such file to load -- truncate_html.rb when trying to Migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

After updating my Ruby on Rails and Spree app to `Rails ~ 5.1.6` (previously `4.3`)  and `Spree ~ 3.5.0.rc2` (previously `3.3`)

I get the following error when trying to migrate my app:

```
LoadError: No such file to load -- truncate_html.rb
```

Followed by:

```
Caused by:
Polyglot::PolyglotLoadError: Failed to load truncate_html using extensions rb
```

the problem seems to be that `trunacte_html` is misshing which is weird, since I'm not familiar with trunacte_html.rb since I've never used it. After looking into the `Polyglot` and `truncate_html`

I've discovered that `trunactehtml` is:

> TruncateHtml is just like the vanilla truncate rails helper, except it
>   respects tags and html entities, and returns valid html.

Yet I've never used or installed this gem? Is it added with the new rails?

I've discovered that `polyglot` is:

> Give your JavaScript the ability to speak many languages

Yet also another gem I've never installed or used.

I've wanted to install the [trunacte gem](https://github.com/hgmnz/truncate_html), but it's 4 years old and meant for rails 2 or 3.

Polygot is running on it's latest versin 0.3.5

**Does anyone know what is the cause of the error and how to solve it?**

**EDIT**

Solved: I solved it by installing gem `truncate_html` , '~> 0.9.3'

Comment: Have you check if still has support?

Comment: @JuanseCora I solved it by installing `gem 'truncate_html', '~> 0.9.3'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by installing gem `truncate_html', '~> 0.9.3`